# Data safety section in Google Play User Data policy: <p>Invalid Data safety form</p>

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console

I fill all the details properly. Check all the step clearly. But this problem occurs.
What is the Solution of this.

I am trying to upload new release of Our application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.